# Transpose 3 column excel with K:V into column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a 3 column excel file I'm reading into pandas with basically k:v pairs in columns

```
                        stuff     Unnamed: 1            Unnamed: 2
0                    animal:dog            NaN                   NaN
1                   color:brown            NaN                   NaN
2                        age:12            NaN                   NaN
3                  height: 60cm   doctor: mike  visit date: 01/12/21
4   unique animal id:3597230857   doctor id: 2                   NaN
5                           NaN            NaN                   NaN
6                   animal: cat            NaN                   NaN
7                  color: orage            NaN                   NaN
8                        age:21            NaN                   NaN
9                  height: 40cm   doctor: mike                   NaN
10   unique animal id: 95760203   doctor id: 2   visit date:05/21/20
11                          NaN            NaN                   NaN
12                animal: snake            NaN                   NaN
13                 color: orage            NaN                   NaN
14                        age:3  doctor:sally                    NaN
15     unique animal id: 325125    doctor id:1   visit date:05/21/20
16                          NaN            NaN                   NaN
17                          NaN            NaN                   NaN
18                 animal: bird            NaN                   NaN
19                  color: blue            NaN                   NaN
20                 height: 40cm  doctor:sally                    NaN
21  unique animal id: 496701275    doctor id:1   visit date:05/21/20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I need to not only tie the information in unnamed:1 & unnamed:2 to the unique animal ID as this is how I will track the animal but also transpose these columns where everything to the left of the ":" is the column header w/ appropriate values.

```
  animal   color   age  height(cm)  unique animal id doctor  dictir id visit date
0    dog   brown  12.0        60.0        3597230857   mike          2 2021-01-12
1    cat   orage  21.0        40.0          95760203   mike          2 2020-05-21
2  snake  orange   3.0         NaN            325125  sally          1 2020-05-21
3   bird    blue   NaN        40.0         496701275  sally          1 2020-05-21
```

Currently working off of

```
    for source in sources:
        df = pd.read_excel(source)
    df['new_heading'] = df['stuff'].str.split(':').str[0]
    df['new_value'] = df['stuff'].str.split(':').str[1]
    df.loc[df['new_heading'] == "animal", 'new_aninmal'] = df['new_value']
    df.loc[df['new_heading'] == "color", 'new_color'] = df['new_value']
    df.loc[df['new_heading'] == "age", 'new_age'] = df['new_value']
    df.loc[df['new_heading'] == "height", 'new_height'] = df['new_value']
    df.loc[df['new_heading'] == "unique animal id", 'new_uid'] = df['new_value']
```

but it gives this waterfall output (expectedly so)

```
                          stuff     Unnamed: 1            Unnamed: 2       new_heading   new_value new_aninmal new_color new_age new_height     new_uid
0                    animal:dog            NaN                   NaN            animal         dog         dog       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
1                   color:brown            NaN                   NaN             color       brown         NaN     brown     NaN        NaN         NaN
2                        age:12            NaN                   NaN               age          12         NaN       NaN      12        NaN         NaN
3                  height: 60cm   doctor: mike  visit date: 01/12/21            height        60cm         NaN       NaN     NaN       60cm         NaN
4   unique animal id:3597230857   doctor id: 2                   NaN  unique animal id  3597230857         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN  3597230857
5                           NaN            NaN                   NaN               NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
6                   animal: cat            NaN                   NaN            animal         cat         cat       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
7                  color: orage            NaN                   NaN             color       orage         NaN     orage     NaN        NaN         NaN
8                        age:21            NaN                   NaN               age          21         NaN       NaN      21        NaN         NaN
9                  height: 40cm   doctor: mike                   NaN            height        40cm         NaN       NaN     NaN       40cm         NaN
10   unique animal id: 95760203   doctor id: 2   visit date:05/21/20  unique animal id    95760203         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN    95760203
11                          NaN            NaN                   NaN               NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
12                animal: snake            NaN                   NaN            animal       snake       snake       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
13                 color: orage            NaN                   NaN             color       orage         NaN     orage     NaN        NaN         NaN
14                        age:3  doctor:sally                    NaN               age           3         NaN       NaN       3        NaN         NaN
15     unique animal id: 325125    doctor id:1   visit date:05/21/20  unique animal id      325125         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN      325125
16                          NaN            NaN                   NaN               NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
17                          NaN            NaN                   NaN               NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
18                 animal: bird            NaN                   NaN            animal        bird        bird       NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN
19                  color: blue            NaN                   NaN             color        blue         NaN      blue     NaN        NaN         NaN
20                 height: 40cm  doctor:sally                    NaN            height        40cm         NaN       NaN     NaN       40cm         NaN
21  unique animal id: 496701275    doctor id:1   visit date:05/21/20  unique animal id   496701275         NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN   496701275
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section starts with `animal`, so create a counter that acknowledges that. the counter will be used in pivoting the data:

```
reshape = (
    df.assign(counter=np.where(df.stuff.str.startswith("animal:"), 1, 0).cumsum())
    .melt("counter")
    .dropna()
    .drop(columns="variable")
)
```

Here we split the column with `:` and pivot the data; the counter ensures a unique index, which is required for a successful pivot:

```
    (
    reshape.value.str.split(":", expand=True)
    .assign(counter=reshape.counter)
    .pivot("counter", 0, 1)
)
    

        age     animal  color   doctor  doctor id   height  unique animal id    visit date
counter                                 
1       12      dog     brown   mike      2        60cm     3597230857  01/12/21
3       21      cat     orage   mike      2        40cm     95760203    05/21/20
5       3       snake   orage   sally     1         NaN     325125  05/21/20
8      NaN      bird    blue    sally     1        40cm     496701275   05/21/20
```

Comment: Man, so I can pandas with the best of them when it comes to joins, apply, loc/iloc, agg and other functions, but when it comes to melt/pivot/stack/unstack I have to just throw spaghetti at the wall in IPython and hope something comes out the right way.  How do you get good enough at these types of functions to make them part of your standard toolbelt?  Or do you also just throw spaghetti until it works?

Comment: I feel it comes with practice; over time, you build an intuition of what works; also helps when you answer lots of questions on stack overflow, as well as learning from other answers. and well all fails, throw spaghetti until it works:)

Comment: This works well for me up until the ".pivot('counter', 0, 1)" where I get a Value error for duplicate counter values in the index.

Comment: @emgp, same data you shared?

Comment: @sammywemmy Yup. printing the output w/o the .pivot("counter", 0, 1) shows https://imgur.com/pchooy0

Your second code block was adjusted to be 
print(reshape.value.str.split(":", expand=True).assign(counter=reshape.counter))

Comment: ok. have a look at the data before the pivot, and see if you can pick out the duplicate rows. maybe run `.duplicated()` to see. I'm using the exact data you shared, so wondering where the duplicates are coming from, as it works fine when I ran it again

Answer (score 0):

```
# find the animal group
df['index'] = df['stuff'].fillna('').str.contains('animal:').cumsum()

# stack to drop na and group animal group
obj = df.set_index('index').stack().droplevel(1)
# print(obj)

# split and expand, then strip blank space
df = obj.str.split(':', expand=True).applymap(str.strip)

# reset_index and unstack
dfn = df.set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()
# print(dfn)
```

output:

```
print(obj)

index
1                     animal:dog
1                    color:brown
1                         age:12
1                   height: 60cm
1                   doctor: mike
1           visit date: 01/12/21
1    unique animal id:3597230857
1                   doctor id: 2
2                    animal: cat
2                   color: orage
2                         age:21
2                   height: 40cm
2                   doctor: mike
2     unique animal id: 95760203
2                   doctor id: 2
2            visit date:05/21/20
3                  animal: snake
3                   color: orage
3                          age:3
3                   doctor:sally
3       unique animal id: 325125
3                    doctor id:1
3            visit date:05/21/20
4                   animal: bird
4                    color: blue
4                   height: 40cm
4                   doctor:sally
4    unique animal id: 496701275
4                    doctor id:1
4            visit date:05/21/20
dtype: object

print(dfn)

       age animal  color doctor doctor id height unique animal id visit date
    1   12    dog  brown   mike         2   60cm       3597230857   01/12/21
    2   21    cat  orage   mike         2   40cm         95760203   05/21/20
    3    3  snake  orage  sally         1    NaN           325125   05/21/20
    4  NaN   bird   blue  sally         1   40cm        496701275   05/21/20
```

---

sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
data = [{'stuff': 'animal:dog', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'color:brown', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'age:12', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'height: 60cm',
  'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor: mike',
  'Unnamed: 2': 'visit date: 01/12/21'},
 {'stuff': 'unique animal id:3597230857',
  'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor id: 2',
  'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': nan, 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'animal: cat', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'color: orage', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'age:21', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'height: 40cm', 'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor: mike', 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'unique animal id: 95760203',
  'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor id: 2',
  'Unnamed: 2': 'visit date:05/21/20'},
 {'stuff': nan, 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'animal: snake', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'color: orage', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'age:3', 'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor:sally', 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'unique animal id: 325125',
  'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor id:1',
  'Unnamed: 2': 'visit date:05/21/20'},
 {'stuff': nan, 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': nan, 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'animal: bird', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'color: blue', 'Unnamed: 1': nan, 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'height: 40cm', 'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor:sally', 'Unnamed: 2': nan},
 {'stuff': 'unique animal id: 496701275',
  'Unnamed: 1': 'doctor id:1',
  'Unnamed: 2': 'visit date:05/21/20'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```